# Disable ASP.Net button click until after page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an ASPxButton to export some data from a webpage in different formats. There is a drop down (combo box) list of export formats. After a format is selected, the page has to reload. There are issues if that button is clicked before the page is fully reloaded, so I want to either disable the ability to click that button until the page is fully loaded.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Set the button's disabled attribute in your HTML, then in your jQuery enable it (by removing the disabled attribute) when the DOM is ready.

HTML:

```
<button id="foo" disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#foo").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: It's an ASPxButton not an HTML button.  I tried what you suggested, but it appears the Enabled="False" attribute of the ASPxButton overrides the jquery.

Comment: So in that case, could you just set Enabled="False" and set it to True with jQuery when ready? ```$("#foo").attr("Enabled",True);```

Comment: I tried that, it is also not working.  The jQuery is updating the attribute on the client side, but it is not actually changing the .Net code. Therefore, the Enabled property is still set to False.

Answer (score 0):

Initially keep disabled the button and make enable after `document` is ready. Use `.on()` and `change as event` when combobox/dropdownlist is changed. Like this.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn" disabled="disabled">Export</button>
```

**JS**

```
//Enabled after document is ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');
});
//Disabled when dropdownlist is changed
$(document).on('change', 'combobox #id or .class', function(event) {
    $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```